# How to tell cron to find paths to tools?

Tags: cron

Is there a way to indicate to [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) how/where to find (paths to)  tools such as `python`, `nmap`, `php` and so on?

I ask this because when I schedule a job using `crontab -e`, I always need to specify the full path of `python`, `nmap` and whatever other tool I want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from `man 5 crontab`:

> ```
>    Several environment variables are set up automatically by  the  cron(8)
>    daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the
>    /etc/passwd  line  of   the   crontab's   owner.   PATH   is   set   to
>    "/usr/bin:/bin".   HOME,  SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings
>    in the crontab; LOGNAME is the user that the job is running  from,  and
>    may not be changed.
> ```

So, `PATH` is set by cron to `"/usr/bin:/bin"`. Now, to add more paths to the `PATH` to be used by cron, just edit the crontab file (using `crontab -e` command) and add, for example the following line somewhere at the beginning:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

See also this Q&A from StackOverflow: [crontab PATH and USER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129381/crontab-path-and-user).